# Redirect to an action method is not happening

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am a beginner to MVC and JQuery.I am displaying records from the database in a table.Now,after deletion of one of the records,the table should not display the records anymore.This is what I am doing to achieve that.

I have 2 action methods in the controller.
Index action method

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        Provider providerList = new Provider();
        IList<Provider> providers = DAL.GetListofProviders.ToList();

        int pageSize = 5;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(providers.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
    }
```

The delete action method

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        DAL.DeleteProvider(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

My view is as shown

```
 @using PagedList;
 @using PagedList.Mvc;
 @model IPagedList<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider>
 @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
 <head>
    <title>LIST OF PROVIDERS</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Providers List</h1><br/>
    <a class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1" href="/Provider/Create">Create</a><br/>

    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tblData">
    <tr>
        <th>Provider Type</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Certification</th>
        <th>Specialization</th>
        <th>SSN</th>
        <th>Facility Name</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>

    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:viewModel.DataList">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ProviderType"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: Certification"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: Specialization"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: SSN"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: FacilityName"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ContactNumber"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ContactEmail"></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:$root.Edit">Edit</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:$root.Delete">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
    Page @(Model.PageCount<Model.PageNumber? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    @Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {    page        }) )
   </div>   
   </body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-   latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

The JS for delete

```
function ProviderViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.ProviderID = ko.observable("");
self.ProviderType = ko.observable("");
self.FirstName = ko.observable("");
self.LastName = ko.observable("");
self.Certification = ko.observable("");
self.Specialization = ko.observable("");
self.SSN = ko.observable("");
self.ContactNumber = ko.observable("");
self.ContactEmail = ko.observable("");
self.FacilityName = ko.observable("");
self.DataList = ko.observableArray([]);

var Provider =
    {
        ProviderID: self.ProviderID,
        ProviderType: self.ProviderType,
        FirstName: self.FirstName,
        LastName: self.LastName,
        Certification: self.Certification,
        Specialization: self.Specialization,
        SSN: self.SSN,
        ContactNumber: self.ContactNumber,
        ContactEmail: self.ContactEmail,
        FacilityName: self.FacilityName,
    };

self.Provider = ko.observable();
self.Providers = ko.observableArray();

// Delete Provider
self.Delete = function (Provider) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')) {
        var id = Provider.ProviderID();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Provider/Delete/" + Provider.ProviderID(),
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: ko.toJSON(id),
            success: function (data) {
                self.Providers.remove(Provider);
                //   alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
            }
        }).fail(
             function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                 alert(err);
             });
    }
}
```

The record is getting deleted,but I see the deletion only if I refresh the page.In other words,The redirect to Index in the delete action method is not happening.Could anyone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I guess it's because the JS call is async, you should include (async:false)
You don't really need JS to get to the Delete Action, you can call the action using the HTML Helpers.
P.S. Don't use static classes to access your data and business layers like in (DAL.DeleteProvider(id);) try to work with instances and use OOP.

Comment: This is for a Demo app where we have to use AJAX apparently.I will change the static classes part.Could you tell me where I have to use async:false.

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: "/Provider/Delete/" + Provider.ProviderID(),
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: ko.toJSON(id),
            success: function (data) {
                self.Providers.remove(Provider);
                //   alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
            }

Comment: I added the 'async:false' to the ajax call,but I still have to refresh the page to see the deletion.

Comment: your are removing from `self.providers` and looping on tbody `viewModel.DataList` i didn't quite get that . knockout is very simple when something like view don't update means either we are not pushing properly or its not a observable . fiddle it up so it can be helpful to track .

Comment: Sorry,I have never used that before and am not sure how to go about it.I will give it a try though